# RethinkDB: How to order by the length of a string field?

Tags: rethinkdb

Suppose I have an article table with a title field. How could I get a list of articles sorted by how long their titles are?

ex. article:

```
{id: '101', title: 'A title', contents: 'Lots of text'}
```

I tried:

```
r.table('story').orderBy(function(doc){return r.row('title').length}).pluck('title')
```

but it's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `split("").count()` as a work around now

```
r.table("story").orderBy(function(doc) {
    return doc("title").split("").count()
}).pluck("title")
```

See https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/264 to track progress on a native method to get the length of a string.

Comment: Doesn't work as expected for UTF-8 strings containing non-ASCII characters like accents or CJK ideographs. According to https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2518 the fix should land in 2.1 or 2.2? 

Answer (score 0):

This was implemented in RethinkDB 2.3, [issue 4228](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4228).

You could do something like

```
r.db('cms')
  .table('story')
  .map(doc => doc.merge({
    title_length: doc('title').default('').count()
  }))
  .orderBy(r.desc('title_length'));
```

However, this is very inefficient, as every time, it will read ALL documents, which is less efficient than comparable SQL implementations, which would only read one column, whereas RethinkDB reads the whole JSON.

You might want to save the title length inside the documents themselves, if you're going to query it often.